# Какому словарю верить в написании мало(-)мальский?

Tags: орфография, слитно-дефис

Орфографический словарь

мало-мальский

---

Большой толковый словарь

МАЛОМАЛЬСКИЙ, -ая, -ое. *Разг*. Самый маленький, незначительный. *Появилась м-ая возможность уехать. Оказать маломальскую услугу.*

---

Русское словесное ударение

маломальский

Comment: ***Ответ справочной службы русского языка***

    Дело в том, что написание этих слов разнится не только в разных словарях, но и в разных изданиях одних и тех же словарей. Это сопряжено с объективными трудностями. В случае возникновения разночтений следует сверяться с последним по времени издания и наиболее полным орфографическим словарем.

Comment: Как вам удалось найти в Большом толковом словаре это слово в разном написании -  слитном и дефисном?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Классики писали ***маломальский***, например:

Сколько я в дом получек перетаскал, а хоть один костюмишко **маломальский** купили мне? [Василий Шукшин. Мой зять украл машину дров! (1969-1971)]

Сегодня она боялась всего: и темноты, которая на самом деле была ей на руку, тишины, как никогда густой и чуткой, выдающей любой **маломальский** звук...[Валентин Распутин. Живи и помни (1974)]

В справочнике под ред. Лопатина (2012 год) - **мало-мальский**. Справочник академический, поэтому может задавать форму написания слов. Это не правила, которые можно обсуждать. Здесь как скажут, так и будем писать.

Comment: См. https://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&from=xx&to=ru&did=&stype=0 и http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: И вот тута: https://books.google.ru/books?id=CavOAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA339&dq=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwju_pb2quXaAhWoApoKHZeQAWwQ6AEISjAH#v=onepage&q=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&f=false