# Какая форма письма более логичная: маломальский или мало-мальский?

Tags: орфография, слитно-дефис

*Ещё в зале была мебель: всяческие диваны, кресла, низкие столики, пуфики и кушетки, все дорогой отделки, но выполненные совершенно в разных стилях и расставленные как попало, без какого-либо **маломальского** соображения* (М. Бабкин, 2005).

1. Мне слитное написание сразу показалось ошибочным, неправильным, нелогичным. И действительно, в словаре РАН предлагается форма **«мало-мальский»**, но в толковом словаре Кузнецова слово пишется слитно.

МАЛОМАЛЬСКИЙ, -ая, -ое. Разг. Самый маленький, незначительный. *Появилась м-ая возможность уехать. Оказать маломальскую услугу.*

2. Меня же интересует, **как четко объяснить норму по существующим правилам** – какие «объективные трудности» не позволяют это сделать? Как мне кажется, нет ничего невозможного, в противном случае следует обращаться к смежным наукам (пусть помогут).

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Дело в том, что написание этих слов разнится не только в разных словарях, но и в разных изданиях одних и тех же словарей. Это сопряжено **с объективными трудностями**.

3. И как пишут слово сейчас **в практических текстах**, какая форма более частотная?

Как бы вы его написали?  Спасибо.

[Какому словарю верить в написании мало(-)мальский?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440505/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Пример: *Но если мать хоть что-нибудь пронюхает раньше времени. Хоть **маломальский** повод…*  [Татьяна Соломатина (2011)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без каких-либо правил и словарей я бы написал это слово слитно.

Действительно, в словарях есть обе формы.

В Нацкорпусе ***мало-мальского*** нет. А вот ***маломальский*** во всех падежах, родах и числах представлен в 61 документе (75 вхождений) от А. Н. Островского до Д. А. Емеца.

P. S. В Викисловаре, например, прилагательное написано слитно, а наречие ***мало-мальски*** с дефисом. Чтобы ответить на все вопросы, нужно покопаться.

**Дополнение** (после ответа-комментария ***slava1947***)

1. Исправил цифры по слитному написанию в сторону увеличения.
2. Дефисное написание – 85 документов (если перейти по ссылке, там указаны 93, восемь из которых – раздельное написание ***мало мальски***).

Comment: В Нацкорпусе «мало-мальского» нет, несмотря на то, что все обязаны писать так, как скомандовала РАН?! Какой ужас, однако! :))

Comment: @Александр Стрелец Александр, спасибо за ответ. Но о каких объективных трудностях говорит Справка? Ведь правила основаны на каких-то логических словообразовательных связях. Вероятно, это тема отношений сложных наречий и прилагательных с дефисным письмом. Там же есть какая-то закономерность (например, существует слово тихий-смирный по образцу тихий-тихий или нет).  На да ладно, в РАН и без нас разберутся.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец  Александр, помните вопрос?  Я о нем вспомнила по двум причинам: недавняя тема про написание слов с повтором и та же книга, которую решил перечитать (магическая и очень смешная и остроумная, редкое сочетание). Как бы вы теперь написали это слово? Ну после моих "размышлений" про слова с повтором.

Comment: @Sharon  Написал бы так же, слитно. Это же не повтор типа *мало-мало, маленький-маленький*.

Comment: А мне кажется, что здесь все условия для использования дефиса: эмоционально-экспрессивное усилительное значение, повтор корня с добавлением суффикса и окончания прилагательного. По сходному образцу  образуется слово "день-деньской".  Хорошая модель.

Comment: @Sharon  Словари еще не пришли к единообразию, Грамота рекомендует писать через дефис. Ну и ладненько.

Comment: Орфографический словарь главнее, его РАН каждый год обновляет.  Это Кузнецов еще не пришел к единообразию (кстати, у него 2014 год).

Answer (score 2):

**Вместо комментария.**

Из ответа **Александра Стрельца**:

> В Нацкорпусе ***мало-мальского*** нет. А вот ***маломальский*** во
> всех падежах представлен в 36 документах (50 вхождений) от А. Н.
> Островского до Д. А. Емеца.

В Нацкорпусе ***мало-мальский*** есть.

См. примеры: [https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexgramm&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=Мало&gramm1=&sem1=&flags1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=Мальский&gramm2=&sem2=&flags2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexgramm&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE&gramm1=&sem1=&flags1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&gramm2=&sem2=&flags2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2)

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, теперь нужны выводы.

Comment: Спасибо. Значит, не умею пользоваться поиском в Нацкорпусе. Я вводил именно слово с дефисом, а надо, как у Вас: "мало" на расстоянии 1 от "мальский". Даже раздельное написание попадается.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Вы не хотели бы исправить свой ответ? Он принят, и из-за этого будет вводить в заблуждение других пользователей (он будет отображаться первым).

Answer (score 1):

> Какая форма письма более логичная: маломальский или мало-мальский?

Логика — это ко мне. Логичнее слитное, потому что нет слова "мальский".

Такое написание представлено во всех авторитетных толковых словарях (Кузнецова, Ефремовой, Ушакова, Ожегова и Шведовой). Дефисного в них нет, но странно то, что во всех этих словарях почему-то есть "мало-мальски" (и только дефисное), что противоречит "маломальский".

РАН привыкла менять нормы (нужно же чем-то заниматься, реформами), руководствуясь чем-то. Так чем же здесь? Есть слово "мало-мало". Можно было бы предположить, что заданное образовано от него. Но эта логика уступает той, что выше.

Наличие двух логик как раз и представляет собою объективные трудности.

Comment: Спасибо, oleedd,, чуть позже почитаю.  Хотела вообще закрыться на время, но про логику-то интересно узнать. :)

Comment: Примечание: если они абсолютно уверены (есть неопровержимые доказательства), что образовано от "мало-мало", то эта логика однозначно выигрывает.

Comment: Они! А вы сами должны думать или нет?  Вспомним "день-деньской".  Что означает эта форма, она же экспрессивная. Откуда там форма прилагательного с суффиксом СК? И т.д. И пишется через дефис, между прочим.

Comment: Не понял. Они — это РАН. Здесь вопрос в абсолютной уверенности в этимологии. Это не ко мне. "День-деньской" не соединить из-за отсутствия гласной посередине.

Comment: Вы видите только форму и сравниваете только форму, а нужно понять внутренний закон этих явлений. Надеюсь, я понятно выражаюсь :))

Comment: Нет там закона, есть принципы, о которых сказал.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо за дискуссию, пока вопрос закрыт. ОН интересный, из него даже конкурс можно было бы сделать,  но не сейчас. Сейчас меня занимает другая тема - про двоеточие и тире.

Comment: *ОН интересный, из него даже конкурс можно было бы сделать* — даже и не представляю, как бы не из чего. Опять текст сочинять?

Comment: Ни в коем случае, только доказательство правильности одной из форм.  Но пока все уже немного устали от конкурсов.

Comment: Да кто вам доказать сможет?! Это к РАН.

Comment: РАН - это не гарантия Высшего разума,  а потренироваться в любом случае неплохо. Решают же люди различные задачи, почему бы и нам не попробовать.

Comment: У обоих вариантов есть логика, так что исключить здесь не получится, можно лишь выбрать лучшее, доказывая свою позицию.

Comment: Победит сильнейший, на то и конкурс :)